# Set and retrieve the session values wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, session-variables

I'm using WooCommerce.
I set my own session on page.php, and trying to pass that session to mini-cart.php, but mini-cart isn't receiving that session.

page.php is like this

```
get_header("english"); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
    <?php
    // Start the loop.
    // session_start();
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        // Include the page content template.
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

        // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
        if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
            comments_template();
        }

        // End of the loop.
    endwhile;
    ?>

</main><!-- .site-main -->
<?php get_sidebar( 'content-bottom' ); ?>
</div><!-- .content-area -->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer();
// Adding my own session below
$_SESSION['menu_lang'] = "english";
```

I'm trying to print that session on mini-cart.php like this

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['menu_lang'])) {
 echo "no session";
} else {
 echo $_SESSION['menu_lang'];
}
```

How can I pass my session to mini-cart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do using following code.

Add below code in your theme's functions.php file

```
function register_session_new(){
    if( ! session_id() ) {
       session_start();
     }
 }

add_action('init', 'register_session_new');
$_SESSION['menu_lang'] = "english";
```

Use this line in your mini-cart.php file or wherever you want to use.

```
echo $_SESSION['menu_lang'] ;
```

Comment: I tried, but now mini-cart is not receiving any products and there's following message

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Session' not found in C:\MAMP\htdocs\woocommerce\wp-content\themes\twentysixteen\page.php:43 Stack trace: #0 C:\MAMP\htdocs\woocommerce\wp-includes\template-loader.php(74): include() #1 C:\MAMP\htdocs\woocommerce\wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('C:\\MAMP\\htdocs\\...') #2 C:\MAMP\htdocs\woocommerce\index.php(17): require('C:\\MAMP\\htdocs\\...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\woocommerce\wp-content\themes\twentysixteen\page.php on line 43

Comment: which wordpress version you are using?

Comment: I'm using 4.9.6

Comment: Ok now I have add the other way to do it check it.

Comment: I tried, and I can echo $_SESSION['menu_lang'] on the page, but not on mini-cart...it's still showing "no session"

Comment: make sure you call your minicart function after the session is set you can set your session at header file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [transients](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/transients/) instead of session.
In wordpress it is highly recommended.

```
set_transient( $transient, $value, $expiration );
get_transient( $transient );
delete_transient( $transient );
```